# How to get the generic class of a list with java reflectioin?

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection, field

I have a local variable List or some other List
I want to get the generic class of this list variable.

The variable is NOT member variable, so do NOT use Field to get the generic class.

The method should be

```
public Class<?> getGenericClass(List<E> list){

      //somehow to return Class E

}
```

---

*Edit:* I tried the solution by @Radiodef but I got the exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

at the line `Class genericClazz = (Class) pt .getActualTypeArguments()[0]`.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("aaa");
    final Type type = list.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        final ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
        final Class<?> genericClazz = (Class<?>) pt
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(genericClazz.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way it can be done:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

static <E> Class<E> getClassE(List<E> list) {
    Class<?> listClass = list.getClass();

    Type gSuper = listClass.getGenericSuperclass();
    if(!(gSuper instanceof ParameterizedType))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)gSuper;

    Type tArg = pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if(!(tArg instanceof Class<?>))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Class<E> classE = (Class<E>)tArg;
    return classE;
}
```

However, the `List` you pass in **must** be a subclass with a concrete type.

E.g. if you call

```
... = getClassE( new ArrayList<String>() );
```

it will throw: because generics are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so the `Class<E>` is not normally available at run time.

Usually when this pattern is used, you use an anonymous subclass e.g.:

```
//                                       vv
... = getClassE( new ArrayList<String>() {} );
```

But you could also do

```
class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {}
... = getClassE( new StringList() );
```

When we create a subclass like this, the `Class<E>` gets stored and we can retrieve it via the reflection in the first part of my answer.

Also see: http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html.

And Ideone example in action: http://ideone.com/O2Gztj.

Comment: I got java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

at  pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

Comment: That's interesting. Did you copy it exactly? (All of my casts are guarded, so you should get `IllegalArgumentException` if there's a problem, not `ClassCastException`.) And what did you pass to it?

Comment: Please see me new comments

Comment: Read the second part of my answer again. If you are going to use this code, everywhere you do `new ArrayList<MyType>()` you need to change it to `new ArrayList<MyType>() {}` or create a subclass of ArrayList like `class MyList extends ArrayList<MyType> {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler treats List as List (without type information) so there is no way to get the generic type via reflection.

What you can do:

- scan each element of the list and find the most specific common super class
- scan each element of the list and find all common interfaces

Both approaches would iterate over the list elements and then reflectively scan the class hierarchy.